# dc.js line chart - user selectable BINS and date range

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dc.js

I am using dc.js to generate line chart successfully, however i want to create UI similar to the attached image.

1) user can select the bins in LHS
2) user can see and change the date range on RHS(brush window on the chart)

[image]

So, does DC chart provides these options or do i have to manually code for the above UI ?

Comment: dc.js is always customized through code, so yes, you will have to manually code it unless you find an example to copy and paste. If I understand correctly, you want to change the bin width based on what the user clicked. [The "switching time intervals" example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/switching-time-intervals.html) might be a good start.

Comment: As for changing the date range, you can see an example of "focus and range charts" [on the main page](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/) - that's probably easiest for users. I'm not clear from your screen shot what you're trying to do.

Comment: thanks @Gordon for the quick response,  the line chart will be drawn on timestamp datasets. what i am trying to achieve is 1) let user select bins according to day / month / quarter for the line chart and also 2) when user is using brush window to select a particular date range, i want to let him see his selected date ranges on RHS and also through that he can change dates and hit apply to see result on the chart.

Comment: Sounds good! I've pointed out how to do 2/3 of those things. You'll just have to use a date picker control for the last one. Once you try something, feel free to update your question of you get stuck.